# Django 1.11 static files not loading

Tags: python, django, static

```
<link href="{% static 'vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

`<link href= "{% static 'css/grayscale.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">`

Setting.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'static')
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'templates'),)
```

There are static files in my directory, I have tried every possible solution.

Comment: what's the path to the vendor folder?

Comment: thats for the css files,

Comment: so what's the path to the static folder in your project directory?

Comment: Did you load the module with `{% load static %}` at the top?

Comment: Precise how you use it: under PyCharm, Linux, Windows, which version of Python, and so on. You have to explain the context.

Comment: Have you run `manage.py` collectstatic? Is this in development or production?